# VS2010 then SP2010

Tags: sql-server

Goal:
Using Sharepoint 2010 in my client computer with Windows server 2008

Problem:
Should I install Visual Studio 2010 first then install Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 64-bit and then install SQL server 2012?

What chronological order should I install?

Background:
I'm a newbie in Sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install SQL Server before you install SharePoint.  SharePoint saves all of its configuration data in the database and if you don't install SQL Server first, it will install SQL Server Express 2008 first.  You also need to configure service accounts for SQL Server, as SharePoint will need them to access your database.

<strike>Then, as [Dave Wise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2648/dave-wise) mentioned, installing and patching SharePoint 2010 is usually the standard procedure.</strike>

Edit:  Removed blurb about Visual Studios.  Could not find a Microsoft Best Practice regarding it.

Comment: I've had no problem installing VS2010 first. The order you install VS in doesn't matter here.

Comment: Yes, I can agree with this.  Visual Studios installs all of the solution templates regardless of whether there's a SharePoint install or not.  I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I've always installed and patched SharePoint prior to installing Visual Studio and that seems to work well.